# transform "once a month" "several times a month" etc. into probabilities

Tags: statistics, probability

How to translate the following occurrences into probabilities? The given time period during which these events can occur is 1 year.

```
"Once in a 100 years"
"Once in 10 years"
"Once a year"
"5 times a year"
"5 times a month"
```

Following Aimery's explanations below, I would translate above occurrences into probabilities as follows:

```
n   1 year period     X    Probability   in %   Calculation
1   1               100    0,01          1      (1x1)/100
1   1                10    0,10          10     (1x1)/10
1   1                 1    1,00          100    (1x1)/1
5   1                 1    5,00          500    (5x1)/1
5   1              1/12    60,00         6000   (5x1)/1/12
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** We now know OP wants probabilities over a year, and assumes "several" is about five.

I'll assume events are evenly distributed over time, so a [uniform probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) may be assumed.

For event `n occurrences in X years`, the probability will be: `n/X` (or rather `n*(1 year)/(X years)`.

Basically, this is proportionality: `(duration you are interested in)*(number of events during the sample period)/(duration of the sample period)`.

However, you have to bear in mind that, by definition, probabilities are between 0 and 1. So the above formula becomes: `minimum( (duration you are interested in)*(number of events during the sample period)/(duration of the sample period), 1)` or in your case `minimum( n/X, 1)`

**Old answer**

First of all, we need more context: are we looking at the probability of said event occurring within the next hundred millennia, or within the next few seconds? Something that happens "once a year" will most likely (although it depends upon the distribution of probability and thus your model) have a probability of one in the next millennium and zero in the next millisecond.

Also, "several times a year" can apparently refer to any number of occurrences between 2 and 12, which is (most likely) a six-fold variation of the probability.

Overall, this sounds more like a linguistics question than a programming (or mathematics) one.

Comment: Hi Aimery, thanks for your reply! the timeframe we look at is a 100 years. Well, we can substitute several by let's say 5 times a year/month. Assuming these assumptions, is it possibly to create probabilities?

Comment: Sorry, the timeframe we look at is just a year and not 100 years.

Comment: @user969113 It is possible. Can you edit the question to specify the time frame? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @user969113 Just realised I forgot to mention probabilities are capped at one, so I edited it in.

Comment: Hey Aimery, I see your point with probabilities between 0 and 1. However, I do not understand how to evaluate max( n/X, 1). Sorry...

Comment: Sorry, it should be the minimum of `n/X` and 1, not the maximum.

Comment: no worries, however, it still leaves me blind in how to evaluate/calculate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171097/discussion-between-aimery-and-user969113).